# How can the constitutionality of a Law be challenged in the USA?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law

Can the constitutionality of a law in the United States be challenged other than through the Supreme Court?

Comment: FWIW, it is virtually impossible to challenge the constitutionality of a law in the first instance in the U.S. Supreme Court. One cannot go to the Supreme Court (except in some very narrow circumstances involving lawsuits of one state against another and certain cases involving diplomats) without first raising the issue in a lower court.

Comment: Also, while it is only effective within the relevant governmental body, the Attorney General of the federal government (in cases involving the federal government's interpretation) and the AG of a state with respect to state employees can make internally binding determinations in the form of an opinion letter that a statute is unconstitutional, which are effective until a court with jurisdiction over employees in question rules otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

In the United States, the constitutionality of a law can be challenged in any court. Unless and until the court is reversed by a higher court, then the law will be considered unconstitutional and invalid.

A jury can also theoretically nullify a law for any reason, including unconstitutionality, however, the jury's finding will only hold for that one case that they are trying.

Comment: An important note on challenging any law in the United States is "Standing" meaning the challenging party (the plaintiff) must have been actually harmed by the law's implementation.  You cannot challenge on behalf of the harmed party nor can you challenge on theoretical harm that could come to you through this law.

Comment: "Unless and until the court is reversed by a higher court, then the law will be considered unconstitutional and invalid." Strictly speaking the ruling of a court other than the U.S. Supreme Court applies with binding effect only to the parties and to other courts subject to the jurisdiction of that court, although it is persuasive authority in other courts. Jury nullification is also only effective, for the most part, in criminal cases, as a jury verdict in a civil case can be reversed if under the correct law no evidence in the record supports the verdict.

Answer (score -4):

It is not true that a law's constitutionality may be challenged in any court. [Rather](http://litigation.findlaw.com/legal-system/federal-vs-state-courts-key-differences.html):

> State Laws and the Federal Constitution
>
> Federal courts may hear cases concerning state laws if the issue is
>   whether the state law violates the federal Constitution. Suppose a
>   state law forbids slaughtering animals outside of certain limited
>   areas. A neighborhood association brings a case in state court against
>   a defendant who sacrifices goats in his backyard. When the court
>   issues an order (called an injunction) forbidding the defendant from
>   further sacrifices, the defendant challenges the state law in federal
>   court as an unconstitutional infringement of his religious freedom.
>
> Some kinds of conduct are illegal under both federal and state laws.
>   For example, federal laws prohibit employment discrimination, and the
>   states have added their own laws which also forbid employment
>   discrimination. **A person can go to federal or state court to bring a
>   case under the federal law or both the federal and state laws. A
>   state-law-only case can be brought only in state court.**

(Emphasis mine).

Comment: No, a law's constitutionality under the federal constitution can be challenged in any court, as the bolded text makes clear.

Comment: You're incorrect, of course. If the law in question is a state law it can only go to state court.

Comment: I'm not incorrect. A question about whether a state law complies with the federal constitution is a question arising under the constitution or laws of the United States, which, [by federal statute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1331), the district courts have jurisdiction over. Many cases that end up striking down state laws as unconstitutional started in the federal courts. As the bolded text says, a case under federal law or both federal and state laws can go to federal or state court. The federal constitution is a federal law.

Comment: Also, the bolded text is not quite correct. [State-law-only cases can still be brought in federal court if they're between citizens of different states and the amount in controversy exceeds $75,000.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1332) The bolded text ignores diversity jurisdiction. But that doesn't matter for this question, because whether a state law violates the federal constitution falls under federal question jurisdiction.

Comment: To have state claim in fed ct, cause of action must arise under fed law. To arise under, SCOTUS said the law in question must provide cause of action for claim. Fed question jurisdiction is appropriate in actions based on state law if there is a federal issue within the case and it is raised, disputed, substantial, and capable of resolution in federal court without disrupting the Congressional-approvred balance between the state and fed courts. Not only that, the federal question must appear in the well-pleaded complaint. http://federalpracticemanual.org/chapter2/section3#footnoteref16_04oeacf

Comment: "To have state claim in fed ct, cause of action must arise under fed law." Wrong. Federal courts also have diversity jurisdiction, and can hear state-law-only claims if they fall within diversity jurisdiction. The cause of action only has to involve federal law if the case is under federal question jurisdiction.

Comment: Obviously. As far as I can tell, though, you're the only one mentioning diversity jurisdiction. However, since it is not relevant, nobody else is addressing it. Thanks for reminding it exists, though ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70061/discussion-between-cpast-and-a-fm).

Comment: Also, one can bring an action for declaratory or injunctive relief against the government official charged with enforcing a state law in federal court against the state official charged with enforcing the law (often a governor, or in election law cases, a secretary of state).

Comment: The federal rules of civil procedure specifically provide procedural guidance for federal court challenges of state laws in FRCP 5.1. https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_5.1

Comment: If you mean to say a state official may be sued, then you're right. If you mean to say that a state may waive its immunity and subsequently appear in court, then you're right. Or, if you mean that Congress can enact legislation to waive state immunity in certain circumstances; or if you mean that you may sue subdivisions of the state, e.g., cities, counties, etc., then you're right. Outside of those four exceptions, states are immune from being sued in federal court by citizens or foreign countries.